# How to use Spring Data JPA methods returning a Stream in a try-with-resources block in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, kotlin

So I want to create a `Spring Boot` with `Spring Data JPA` project using `Kotlin` and lets say I have  a `Person` entity. Lets say like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

   private @GeneratedValue @Id Long id;
   private String name;

   @OneToMany
   private List<Person> friends;

   …
}
```

I would create the following interface to be able to use `Try-with-Resources` and a `Stream<Person>`.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Person p")
    Stream<Person> findAllStream();
}
```

So normally in my service I would do this:

```
@Service
class MyService {

    @Autowired PersonRepository repository;

    List<String> foo() {

       try(Stream<Person> stream = repository.findAllStream()) {
          return stream.flatMap(p -> p.getFriends().stream())
             .map(f -> f.getName())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
       }
    }
 }
```

Now if you want to do this in Kotlin (The IntelliJ converter doesn't produce valid code). I suppose you would normally do something like:

```
class MyService @Autowired constructor(val personRepository: PersonRepository) {
    fun foo() {
        val list = personRepository.findAllStream()
                       .use {{p -> p.friends.stream()}.map {f -> f.name}}
    }
}
```

Only you cant do that since there is no `#use` method on stream and you cant call `#stream()` from a `List`. So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Java 8 support is not yet complete in Kotlin. So you can just declare use on your side like this

```
inline fun <A : AutoCloseable, R> A.use(block: (A) -> R): R {
    try {
        return block(this)
    } finally {
        close()
    }
}
```

The other alternative is to declare it directly on `Stream`

```
inline fun <T, R> Stream<T>.use(block: (Stream<T>) -> R): R {
    try {
        return block(this)
    } finally {
        close()
    }
}
```

**UPD**

If you are new to Kotlin you have to notice that extensions are resolved statically:

> Extensions do not actually modify classes they extend. By defining an extension, you do not insert new members into a class, but merely make new functions callable with the dot-notation on instances of this class.

See more http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically